# What is the right way to use admob in my app

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I just finished my first app, and plan to earn money by admob ads. When I monetise a new app on admob, it want me to search my app in app markets. Does it mean that I should publish my app before put ads in it?

If so, what should I do after getting the admob ad unit id? Copy it into my code and republish a new version of my app which contains the real ads (not the test one)? It sounds stupid to build and publish a new version of app only to put some ads in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the Ad Units on AdMob, and then, you only add the next line when you do the requests in your code:

```
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        
        .addTestDevice("XXXXX")
```

Where "XXXXX" is a the code associated to that specific device, that you obtain in the Logcat. You can add as many devices as you want to test. It is not necessary to remove the lines when compiling or when releasing for Google Play.

Comment: Should I release a dummy version of my app, so that I can search it and start everything on admob?

Comment: You can create the new app in AdMob to obtain the IDs before releasing. After you release the app in Google Play, you can easily link the app with the previous

Answer (score 0):

You should compile your first release with the ad code ready to go.  (That's what I always do).

You use the test script so that you get dummy ads, that their clients don't get charged for, when you're testing.  Then you simply swap out that line for the REAL ad serving code when you're ready to release.

You're not going to get in any trouble if you test with the actual admob code as long as you dont:
1.  Click an ad.  Ever.
2.  Test it a gazillion times.  Use the test ad for that.